# Regex for time in hh:mm am/pm format

Tags: regex

I need to make strict validation of input for a school project, time in format HH:MM am/pm. So far i've got this RegEx expression:

```
(([01]?[0-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ([AaPp][Mm]))
```

here's a working demo: http://regexr.com/3c9b5

The only problem is that it accepts times 13:00 to 19:59

What is the correct regular expresion? RegEx has always been hard for me

Comment: Must you use regex for the validation per the terms of the assignment?

Comment: Well is has to be a String, is there a better way of validating Strings?

Comment: Use a library with built-in string parsing. It'll accept this format and many others besides, plus you then don't own all the mistakes that everyone inevitably makes re: time.

Comment: What about `aM` and `Am` -- are those both valid?

Comment: How about `\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])\s?([AaPp][Mm]))` for optional space between time and meridiem?

Comment: This solution will work so long as 00 is a valid format for HH.  For example - 00:20 PM would pass validation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use:

```txt
\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ([AaPp][Mm]))
EDIT:         ^ changed this from "0" to "1" to not accept 00:00
```

Comment: But it accepts `00:00 pm`, and [there's no such time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock)... 11:59 am goes to 12:00 pm. 11:59 pm goes to 12:00 am.

Comment: that can be changed, nice catch

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
^([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] ([AaPp][Mm])$
```

It will accept 1:00 am, 01:00 AM, 12:00 PM, 11:00 pm, 12:59 Pm. But won't accept 00:00 am or 00:00 PM or 01:60 Am.

Comment: Welcome to SO. ... will accept "aM" and "pM". If it shouldn't use as last group `([AP][Mm]|[ap]m)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
  ([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])\s*([AaPp][Mm])
```

For the following:

10:00AM

10:00PM

10:00am

10:00pm

10:00 pm

10:00 am

10:30PM

23:46am

Answer (score 2):

This regex has 3 parts, separated by the OR operator.
Each part allows for a type of HH 
They are 0[1-9], [1-9], and 1[0-2].

```
/(0[1-9]:[0-5][0-9]((\ ){0,1})((AM)|(PM)|(am)|(pm)))|([1-9]:[0-5][0-9]((\ ){0,1})((AM)|(PM)|(am)|(pm)))|(1[0-2]:[0-5][0-9]((\ ){0,1})((AM)|(PM)|(am)|(pm)))/
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, code-only answers are discouraged. Instead explain the problems with the original code and what you did to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, @miken32, I haven't posted very much on stack. Is there a guideline to this, aside from the before-you-post page, which includes this info.

Comment: Just browse the help section, it's full of info. (And Meta Stack Overflow is probably full of more info than you need at this point!) In regards to this answer, I upvoted you just because you came back to edit. But it does take the concept of DRY (don't repeat yourself) out behind the woodshed for a beating.

Answer (score 1):

I used this regex

```
([0-9]{2})\\/([0-9]{2})\\/([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}) (am|pm)
```

You can try this. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
  String regex = "([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]";
```

This will work for the 24 hours validation

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for the super solution that matches ALL the time case use this regular expression:

```
((1[0-9]|0?[1-9])(:([0-5][0-9])) ?([AaPp][Mm])?|(1[0-9]|0?[1-9]) ?([AaPp][Mm]))(\s+([A-Z]{3,5})?|$)
```

it matches all the following:

- `simple format`: 12:05, 12:04PM, 1pm, 12:05 PM but not 13PM or 28AM
- `time zones`: 12PM MST, 1:00AM MDT or 2pm NZDT

it also doesn't match `45 minute` or `12`. Try here:

https://regex101.com/r/OU5DM4/1