# Joi validating time field

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

There is object with a property time (22:30:00).

```
const schema = Joi.object.keys({
  ...
  transactionDate: Joi.date().required(),
  transactionTime: Joi.time().required(), // ???
  ...
});
```

How to validate a time field using `Joi`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this way

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
   ...
   transactionDate: Joi.string().regex(/^([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})$/)
})
```

Hear I have used simple regex format.

You can also use this : `^([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$`

for AM and PM `\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])([AaPp][Mm]))`

[AM PM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906033/regex-for-time-in-hhmm-am-pm-format)

Comment: How about allowing am/pm in end?

Comment: How about `([\d]{2}:){2}\d{2}` or `\d\d:\d\d:\d\d` or `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` ?? Let us know if these has any drawback.

Comment: The accepted answer is allowing "98:00" as a valid time :p

Comment: @ShanBiswas As this is accepted so it must work with that user. However, it's just a matter of playing with regex. so if you feel that it's not working for you, Kindly have a look in regex and make changes as per your need.