# Regex time field validation fails in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, joi

I am following this [question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545182/joi-validating-time-field) solution to validate a Django's `TimeField` object `06:00:00`
in reactjs. The validation fails with the error `"Checkin Time" with value "06:00:00" fails to match the required pattern: /^([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})$/` What could be wrong with this regex.

This is my Joi schema. Kindly assist

```
schema = {
    checkin: Joi.string()
      .regex(/^([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})$/)
      .label("Checkin Time"),
    checkout: Joi.string()
      .regex(/^([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})$/)
      .label("Checkout Time"),
  };
```

Comment: Your time is of the form DD:DD:DD, but you are trying to match DD:DD. Are you trying to have the seconds portion be optional?

Comment: Yes seconds option should be optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `^` and `$` characters in your regex. They denote the start and end of your string to compare. You basically are saying the value must be exactly two sets of two digit numbers, separated by a colon. However, your example includes seconds (three sets of two digit numbers, separated by colons). In order to support that, while leaving the seconds portion optional, you can do something like this:

```js
/^([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(:[0-9]{2})?$/
```

We basically create another capture group containing the colon and the seconds portion, and make it optional (`?` matches 0 or 1 instance of the pattern)