# Oracle regexp to validate time

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to validate a regular expression in oracle SQL to check Time format:

The desired format I want to check is:

```
2/27/2020 3:53:02 PM
```

I have already created a regexp for a date format such as:

```
20200227 --> using REGEXP_LIKE('20190222', '^\d{4}(0[1-9]|(1[0-2]))(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$')
```

Could someone give me a hint for the time format?

Comment: Validating date with a regex is a "fragile" idea. What about leap years, variable amount of days in different months? These regexps are rahter unwieldly, also called "readonly".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good point, but the idea here is to check the format: for ex Year cannot be 02, neither a month can be 13 and neither a day can me 32 nor the time can be 25. I hope you get the idea. I just want to check the "time" mask

Comment: If you just need a time regex, see [Regex for time in hh:mm am/pm format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906033). It is a very frequent pattern, there are a lot of similar threads on SO.

Comment: A better approach is to use data type conversion to validate a string. If you're on Oracle 12cR2 or later there is a new built-in `validate_conversion()` which can handle this. [Here is a db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9fb5e92499361704d68453ddd7f8e51a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking into string Regex, I found that this one does the job that I'm looking for:

```
REGEXP_LIKE('2/27/2020 3:53:02 PM','^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M\z')
```

Answer (score 3):

To me, it looks as if you started it **wrong**. If you want to validate *date* (*time*) format, you're storing it as a string, which is a big mistake.

If you set that column (or whatever it is) as `DATE`, which - in Oracle - contains both date and time, then database will take care that you can enter only valid values.

Format you mentioned, or any other, is matter of **display**, not **storage**.

---

One option is to force `TO_DATE` conversion; something like this:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> set ver off
SQL> select to_date('&date_value', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am') result from dual;
Enter value for date_value: 2/27/2020 3:53:02 pm

RESULT
-------------------
27.02.2020 15:53:02

SQL> /
Enter value for date_value: 13/54/2020 x:23:83 am
select to_date('13/54/2020 x:23:83 am', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss am') result from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL>
```

So: if conversion works, then format is OK. Otherwise, you entered something *stupid* and conversion won't pass. Such a code can be used as a function which returns e.g. Boolean.

Comment: This is an extended comment rather than an actual answer. However, it is undoubtedly correct.

Comment: Indeed, just assume that I cannot store it as a date, and I want to preserve (check) that specific display...

Comment: I added some more info. Have  a look, please.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regular expression as the edge cases will make the expression long and complicated (i.e. months can have 28-31 days, leap years every 4 years ... except for multiples of 100 ... except for multiples of 400).

For example, your date regular expression `^\d{4}(0[1-9]|(1[0-2]))(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$` would validate `20190229` or `20200230` or `20200931` neither of which are valid dates.

A time regular expression is easier as you only have hours 0-23, minutes 0-59, seconds 0-59 (assuming you are ignoring leap seconds) and possibly fractional seconds and would be:

```sql
([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d(\.\d+)?
```

However, a simpler way is just to try to perform a conversion to a `DATE` and if it fails then you know it isn't valid. If you are on Oracle 12.2 or later then you can use the built-in [`VALIDATE_CONVERSION` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD):

```sql
SELECT validate_conversion( '20200230000000' AS DATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' )
FROM   DUAL
```

If you are on an earlier version then you can create a custom function to try and perform the conversion and if an exception occurs then you know the input is invalid:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION isValidDate(
  date_string  IN VARCHAR2,
  format_model IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'FXYYYYMMDDHH24MISS'
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  d DATE;
BEGIN
  d := TO_DATE( date_string, format_model );
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
/
```