# Verifying if string is in a valid time format

Tags: time, coldfusion, cfml

I know how to verify if something is a valid date

```
mydate = "1/2/2001";
writeoutput(isDate(mydate));
```

How do I verify if it is a valid time?

```
mytime = "12:42 pm";
writeoutput(isTime(mytime));
```

Does not work because `isTime()` does not exist.

Comment: You could use regex for this.  Here's a link that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906033/regex-for-time-in-hhmm-am-pm-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out if something is a valid time, the `isDate()` function works too.

```
mytime = "12:42 pm";
writeoutput(isDate(mytime));
```

**Update**

Based on feedback from BKBK, I looked for an approach that does not accept so many variations. I found this

```
locale = getLocale();

writeOutput("Locale is: " & locale & "<br>");

// accepted
writeoutput(LSisDate("12:42 pm", locale));
writeoutput(LSisDate("12:42", locale));
writeoutput(LSisDate("22:00", locale));
writeoutput("<hr />");
// rejected
writeoutput(LSisDate("1a", locale));
writeoutput(LSisDate("2p", locale));
writeoutput(LSisDate("2:70", locale));
writeoutput(LSisDate("42:00", locale));
writeoutput("<hr />");
// rejected
writeoutput(LSisDate("12 42 pm", locale));
writeoutput(LSisDate("12 42", locale));
writeoutput(LSisDate("22 00", locale));
```

Comment: Hmm, `isDate` is a blunt instrument. So, too, is `isValid`.  For example, `isDate("1a"), isDate("2p"), isValid("time","1a")` and `isValid("time","2p")` will all return Yes.

Comment: I would suggest you build your own custom function to verify if a string is in a valid time format. It is straightforward to do. The constituent parts are, for example, hour={00, 01, ..., 09, 1, 2, 3, ..., 23}, minute={00, 01, 02, ..., 59}, second={00, 01, 02, ..., 59}, delimiter={:}, meridian={AM, am, a.m., A.M., PM, pm, p.m., P.M.}. You could make some of these optional. You could also enforce certain rules, depending on how you wish to represent time. For example, you might allow 7 AM and 07:00, but disallow 7:00. etc.

Comment: Oh, another delimiter is the space character, chr(32)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to leverage Java, you could make use of its DateTimeFormatter class and, roll your own function to validate based on an expected pattern (see Patterns for Formatting and Parsing [in the API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)).

Below is a simple example function to do that. If the pattern matches, the parse method returns a DateTimeFormatter object on success. So a `DateTimeFormatter object` = `true`, a
`DateTimeParseException` = `false`. This is identified via try/catch.

```
public boolean function isValidTimeFormat(required string value, required string pattern) {
    try {
        var DateTimeFormatter = createObject("java", "java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter");
        var format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(arguments.pattern);
        var parse = format.parse(arguments.value);

        return true;
    }
    catch(java.time.format.DateTimeParseException e) {
        return false
    }
}

// Note that PM is capitalized as that is required for the pattern to match
writeDump(isValidTimeFormat("12:42 PM", "HH:mm a"));
```

[Example on TryCF.com](https://trycf.com/gist/5037c983433946e8bd18148879884a9d/acf2018?theme=monokai)